# Having a difficulty adding a new form in each new <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my adventure to create a To-Do list application, I've run into another problem. In my code, every time a user clicks `New Category` a new `div` will appear with their custom name and number of forms.

However, when another `div` is created, its' forms are given to the previous `div`. Here's that code:

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="script.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
  $("#new").click(function() {
    var canContinue = true;
    var newCategory = prompt("Enter the name you want for your category:");
     if(newCategory.length === 0){
      confirm("A new category can not be created - nothing was entered in the text area.");
      canContinue = false;
      }
    if(canContinue){
    var categorySections = prompt("Enter the number of sections needed for this category:");
    $("body").append("<div id = \"newDiv\"><p>" + newCategory + "</p></div>");
    }

     for(var i = 0; i < categorySections; i++){
      $("#newDiv").append("<form> Thing to do: <input type = \"text\"></form><br>");
     }
    });
});
</script>
```

So, I tried creating a separate function using the `this` keyword where the forms were created after the `div` was ready, but now no forms are created at all!

Here's that code:

```
 $(function(){
$("#newDiv").ready(function() { 
 for(var i = 0; i < categorySections; i++){
      $(this).append("<form> Thing to do: <input type = \"text\"></form><br>");
     }
});
});
```

So, how do I create forms for each separate `div`?

Comment: Oboy! Only the document has a ready event, and all the elements you're appending has the same ID, and....

Comment: I think [this problem](http://todomvc.com/architecture-examples/jquery/) has already been solved. [In many different ways](http://todomvc.com/).

Comment: The idea is to get practice with the new languages I've learned, not to create a ground-breaking new app. Thank you for the reference, however!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're repeatedly creating divs with the same ID. (a) that's not legal and (b) if you do it anyway, your `$(#newDiv)` selector will always apply to the first one.

Also, you're appending to `#newDiv` outside the `if (canContinue)` check.

Try:

```
if(canContinue){
  var categorySections = prompt("Enter the number of sections needed for this category:");
  var newDiv = $("<div>").appendTo($(document.body));
  var header = $('<p>').text(newCategory).appendTo(newDiv);

  for(var i = 0; i < categorySections; i++){
    newDiv.append("<form> Thing to do: <input type = \"text\"></form><br>");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/NqBc5/)

You can't use the ID `newDiv` multiple times, HTML IDs must be unique. Additionally, your flow can be cleaned up a bit, as below.

```
$(function () {
    $("#new").click(function () {
        var newCategory = prompt("Enter the name you want for your category:");
        if (newCategory.length === 0) {
            confirm("A new category can not be created - nothing was entered in the text area.");
            return false;
        }
        var categorySections = prompt("Enter the number of sections needed for this category:");
        var $div = $("<div />", {
            html: "<p>" + newCategory + "</p>"
        });
        $("body").append($div);

        for (var i = 0; i < categorySections; i++) {
            $div.append("<form> Thing to do: <input type='text'/></form><br>");
        }
    });
});
```